# Magento select query not looping properly using a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have written following code:

```html
try {
    $json = array('success' => true);
    $read = $this->read;
    $readresult = $read->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM brand");

    foreach($readresult as $r) {
        $json['brands'][] = array(
            'id'          => $r['brand_id'],
            'name'        => $r['name'],
            'description' => $r['description'],          
        );
    }

    return $json;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $message = $e->getMessage();
    echo json_encode(array("status" => "500", "error" => $message));
}
```

In this code I am trying to display all the brand records from the database table.

But the problem is when I am trying to output the result the it is only displaying one record.

Can anyone please check what is the problem.

The output of the code above is:

```
{
"success":true,
"products":[
    {
    "id":"4",
    "name":"Test",
    "href":"http:\/\/localhost:8‌​1\/magento\/index.php\/catalog\/product\/view\/id\/4\/",
    "thumb":"http:\/\/localho‌​st:81\/magento\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/0\/thumbnail\/9df78eab33525d08d6e‌​5fb8d27136e95\/images\/catalog\/product\/placeholder\/thumbnail.jpg",
    "pirce":"$11‌​1,111.00"
    }
]}
```

Comment: Guys anyone please help noone there?

Comment: if you need anything else also you can tell me

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
     $json['brands'] = array();
     foreach($readresult as $r) {
            $brand = array(
                'id'          => $r['brand_id'],
                'name'        => $r['name'],
                'description' => $r['description'],          
            );
     array_push($json['brands'],$brand);
        }
```

Comment: it is returning null

Comment: You are retrieving the products using brand information with $json['brands'] array which is in different form now. check the $json['brands'] array before this code and after this code and make proper changes to the product retrieving code.

Comment: result is displaying 1, it is not displaying data

Comment: try {
    $json = array('success' => true);
    $read = $this->read;
    $readresult = $read->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM brand");
     $json['brands'] = array();

    foreach($readresult as $r) {
        $brand = array(
            'id'          => $r['brand_id'],
            'name'        => $r['name'],
            'description' => $r['description'],          
        );
    }

    return array_push($json['brands'],$brand);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $message = $e->getMessage();
    echo json_encode(array("status" => "500", "error" => $message));
}

Comment: check the values in $json['brands'] are correct using die with previous code and updated code. Is it returning only one bran or all brands.

Comment: $json = array('success' => true);
    $read = $this->read;
    $readresult = $read->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM brand");
     $json['brands'] = array();

    foreach($readresult as $r) {
        $brand = array(
            'id'          => $r['brand_id'],
            'name'        => $r['name'],
            'description' => $r['description'],          
        );
    }
    print_r(array_push($json['brands'],$brand));